# MovieClip's children turn null when moved to 2nd frame

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5, preloader

I've made a game on a single frame, and now I've moved it to frame 2 in order to add a preloader on frame 1.

However I've run into a strange problem: all of the top level MovieClips still get initialized, but their children seem to not get initialized.

For example, I have this object winDialog, which has a child inside of it called nextLevelButtonInst.  So I have the line:

```
winDialog.nextLevelButtonInst.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, GotoNextLevel);
```

This works fine when the game is only one frame, but with this 2nd frame it's not working.

When I look at the debug variables, then winDialog logs normal, and it has a child nextLevelButonInst, but that is set to null.  This is the same will almost all the movieclips.

Why would moving to the 2nd frame cause this?  It would make sense if the winDialog was null, since it couldn't find it on the first frame perhaps.  But I don't know why only the child would be null.

This is causing all sorts of problems, it can't find sounds, etc.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a main class? or just have code inside your first frame, anywayS this code will not know of the existence of the stuff you have on your second frame until you are on the second frame.

So add the listener after you are on the second frame and everything should be ok.

Comment: I do use a Main document class. However, even when I'm on the second frame, these items don't load.  When I put this code on the 2nd frame: `trace(winDialog + ", " winDialog.nextLevelButtonInst)`, then it says "[object winDialog], null".  So it's loading the first object but not the second.  This all works if I set everything to export on 1st frame, but then everything loads on the 1st frame and you never see the preloader

Comment: yes but are you trying to access the stuff on the second frame when you get there or when the swf loads? the idea is you first have to do a gotoAndStop(2); but depending on the flash version you use it might not get there right after you do the goto and stop so a check to see if you are on the second frame would help.

Comment: I only try and access the stuff when I get to frame 2.  Wasn't able to figure it out -- thanks anyway though Taires!